# Nature of enlightenment

Tags: philosophy, advaita, other-religions, buddhism, enlightenment

How did different people with different philosophies and ideologies attain the same enlightenment or did they not? Buddha attained enlightenment and so did Adi Shankaracharya, but their philosophies are different (not to mention ramanujacharya, nagarjuna and many others). Or is it the case that we can never really know who attains enlightenment? Well I know that there is similarity between Buddhism and Advaita Vedanta but at the core they are very different. How did they attain the same enlightenment knowing the real truth in two different ways? At least one of them is wrong.

Well some say the truth can be interpreted in different ways but if advaita says self exists and buddhism denies it there is a big problem you can't make them compatible with one another.

I have already asked this question here https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41369/nature-of-enlightenment/41383?noredirect=1#comment67347_41383 and got pretty decent answers, i just wanted to know advaitins view.

Comment: Buddha acted as enlightened from Gaya for moha of buddhist. But actually buddha is avatara of vishnu there is no requirement for enlightened because he is light itself.

Comment: well i'm not spiritual so i want more of philosophical answer. advaita claims "aham brahamasmi"

Comment: Same Moksha can be achieved by various methods. As Ramakrishna Paramhamsa used to say "Jato mat tato path" which means "there are as many paths to moksha as there are doctrines" @dark_prince

Comment: @Pradip Gangopadhyay and @ Srimannarayana K V  has already given a speculative answers. My problem was that the one who follows advaita becomes enlightened after knowing - brahman alone exists and he is that(brahman) while the one who follows buddhism gets enlightenment after he realizes that everything is impermanent and transient these two statement are at the opposite end of the spectrum one says there is self and other says there is no self but still both of them gets the same enlightenment.

Comment: Budha the avatar of Vishnu is different from Buddha who estb Buddhism. K thought that's clearly sorted.

Comment: Actually, Enlightenment is silence, thats why Dakshinamurthi give instructions through silence. Several Vedic hymns end in 'Om shanti' meaning peace, because everything comes out of peace and end in peace i.e. death. Br(A)ma+Vishn(U)+(M)ahesh are the triguna Maya ending in Nirguna silence.Buddha went silent when asked about God. Since, Brahman is the whole, Shankaracharya linked Atman to already Vedas and Puranic Gods, while Buddha started new religion focused on Nirvana. There are all sorts of people who seek Nirvana or Godhead or human life and hence chose Buddhism or Hinduism accordingly.

Comment: In advaita enlightenment or realization is that "Brahman alone exist" extract from your word, then all those who claim that they are enlightened in advaita are actually claiming false and contracdicting advaita itself. Because they should not exist by there own definition of advaita.. @dark_prince..

Comment: @sbharti your assumption that this historic buddha is not the buddha avatara  is disproved by MBTN of srimadacharya.. wherein he mention buddha as the one who comes from Gaya.. and also he is son of sudodhana named jain king son.. let us chat this is clarified by Bannaje Govindacharya himself

Comment: @PrasannaR "they" who are claiming "Brahman alone exist" are Brahman themselves, at the deepest level there is no difference between them and Brahman; (to be more precise there is no level at all) they are Brahman(sat chit ananda) and so do you. Because of Maya  "they" identify themselves as body and mind. I don't see any contradiction. If you are still not satisfied you should post a question.

Comment: First you are contradict yourself who told to whom that they are enlightened when there is second listening entity according to advaita doesn't exist than condition of enlightenment avidhya of maya of seeing second entity rules out that they are enlightened in advaita

Comment: See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fTz6Pc4iDU. Hope this answers your doubt!

Comment: Im not asking question im  saying the enlightened person should not see anybody vanish and be with brahman because his avaidya is destroyed according advaita.. if he sees this world as it is after enlightenment then he is not enlightened.. im not saying every should get enlightened im saying the enlightened person should cease to exist inthe world of avaidya where he is still in avaidya afte enlightenment avaidya should be gone.. and the others who  are still in this avaidya should nt see him he should vanish.. that is the condition of advaita..

Comment: Where do you think is avidya? In the mind? In the body? In the brahman? And where is this "world of avidya" you are talking about?

Comment: Avidya is for brahman according to advaita, that brahman is only satchit ananda (than where is the difference of mind or body )

Comment: Well I'm no expert on advaita and this requires a long discussion. You can start a chat if you really want to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No definitive answer can be given to this question. However, a speculative answer may be given.

Advaita Vedanta enlightenment is attained when the mind becomes still.

> **When the lake of the mind becomes clear and still**, man knows himself
> as he really is, always was, and always will be. **He knows that he is
> the Atman.** His 'personality', his mistaken belief in himself as a
> separate, unique individual, disappears. "Patanjali" is only an outer
> covering, like a coat or a mask, which he can assume or lay aside as
> he chooses. **Such a man is known as a free, illumined soul.**

**How to know God *The Yoga Aphorisms of Patanjali I.3* Commentary by Swami Prabhavananda and Christopher Isherwood**

> :"Now I'd like to say more about the fundamental nature of the mind.
> There is no reason to believe that **the innate mind, the very essential
> luminous nature of awareness**, has neural correlates, because it is not
> physical, not contingent upon the brain. So while agree with
> neuroscience that gross mental events correlate with brain activity, I
> also feel that on a more subtle level of consciousness, brain and mind
> are two separate entities."

Dalai Lama in 'On Luminosity of mind' quoted in '**The Really hard problem** meaning in a material world' by Owen Flanagan

It seems comparing the two quotes that **Advaita Vedanta enlightenment is achieved when the mind disappears** while **Buddhist enlightenment is attained when the mind itself becomes luminous.**

Comment: so is the nature of enlightenment of buddhists and advaitin different? and if this is so which one is correct? and is this sense of correctness subjective?

Comment: Judging by the two quotes they seem to be different. The Advaita experience is ontological while the Buddhist experience is psychological. Both are experiences. So the question boils down to which experience leads to enlightenment. It is not possible to answer this question without experiencing both.

Comment: Can an experience of a Salt be different for Buddhist and advaitin? Experience is an ABSTRACT thing.  So enlightenment will be the same. @dark_prince

Comment: that's what the problem is buddhists approach and advaita approach can't lead to the same Salt.@SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: @dark_prince: Did Buddha himself state that  the nature of enlightenment of buddhists and advaitin different?  I don't think so.  Normally, an enlightened person will not enter into unnecessary arguments. At best, he may provide a terse reply to a query put forth to him.  The hair-splitting arguments are the product of people without actual REALISATION.

Comment: I think that's why attaining enlightenment is difficult. thanks for giving such a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enlightenment is philosophical phenomena each tradition has it's own definition. if one is  not belonjng to that specific   cannot claim that I'm enlightened in that tradition  its like saying I'm PhD in physics submitted thesis in physics but got PhD in chemistry instead.

Now Advaita says that for enlightenment only brahman exists ones illusion must be destroyed completely to be that brahman the whole world illusion. As per this theory enlightened person should vanish from this illusionary world  as he is destroyed illusion aka the world that was only his making.
Since no enlightened person exists in this illusionary world one cannot compare with Buddhist enlightment

For tattvada its realizing oneself and in turn god inside ones heart is enlighment here the criteria of destruction of illusionary world is not there because world is real and ever changing  here both jive and brahman exists confirmed by dwasuparna. Enlightenment is attainment of ones own bliss that is different for different jivas according to their capacity its relative fullness cup is full, bucket is full in it's own capacity as its evident bucket is not same as cup  qualitative same but quantitatively different. There is gradation is difference of bliss in moksha what jiva are having bliss on moksha that is both qualitative and quantitative several thousand less in comparison with brahma the creator even without  moksha brahma have bliss which several times greater than normal jiva in moksha

Answer (score 0):

Two people who has attained enlightenment cannot work on the same philosophy or path. They have to create their own instead.

An enlightened being sees other enlightened being as a replica who is doing the same job but in a different way.

the main task is to make people realise who actually they are, and making them realise who they are is one of the hardest job on this planet.
for this, philosophies are developed, a philosophy is nothing but a thought. A thought of seeing the humanity in its best possible state.

It is obvious that this thought of seeing humanity in its best state must be common to every enlightened being. In reality this thought is the core motive of every philosophy, be it philosophy of science or any other philosophy given by a being.

But when we see, the expanded form of this thought, it looks very different from other expanded forms of this same thought. Sometimes they seems just opposite to each other.

so, wether its Buddha or Adi Shankaracharya, both worked for the same cause.

**example:**

Suppose there are two points A and B.

Now say, there is a men who is sticked with point A, sticking simply means he is calling only point A is true.

Now, You have to make him detach from point A, in order to make him realise what he is calling true is not true for everyone, what will you do? you will disagree with point A in your philosophy.

And same will go for point B.

Now, in this contradiction which really exists in our society, the men will think if point A is not true and B is also not true, Than what is the truth.

In this he will go for self enquiry, which is the ultimate aim of spirituality. Hence every philosophy has its own values, so instead of going through them, go in yourself.
In the end every philosophy becomes true.